Why height: 100% doesn't work when it is under a parent using flex-grow
I am new to web coding, and met a strange behavior when using flexbox.
When a parent is using flex-grow: 1, the child element height: 100% doesn't work.
I saw several solutions but doesn't work for me. Does anyone could explain the reason and share some solutions? Thanks!


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: aqua;
}

main {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  /* Enable flex grow */
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
}

footer {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: brown;
}

div#this_should_fill_main {
  height: 100%;
  /*This doesn't work！*/
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>This is a header</header>
  <main>
    <div id="this_should_fill_main">This is main content</div>
  </main>
  <footer>This is a footer</footer>
</body>

</html>



I tried to add height: 0 to <main>, but when the content is overflow, the footer will not be sticky.
I also tried other solutions mentioned in this queestion How can I make Flexbox children 100% height of their parent?, but make no sense for me.

add align-items: stretch to <main>; no change at all
add align-self: stretch to <div id="this_should_fill_main">; no change at all
use display: flex again in <div id="this_should_fill_main">; it works, but why doesn't only height: 100% work?

Could you please help me to solve:

Why height: 100% doesn't work in this case?
How to solve this without using flexbox again?

Thanks for all your answers!

Add height: 0; or min-height: 0; to main, and it works.
As for the reason why height: 100% doesn't work, you can check this Github issue.
(Code was updated for sticky footer)


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: aqua;
}

main {
  flex: 1 0 auto; /* Enable flex grow */
  height: 0;
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
}

footer {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: brown;
}

div#this_should_fill_main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; /*This doesn't work！*/
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  overflow: scroll;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>This is a header</header>
    <main>
      <div id="this_should_fill_main">
        This is main content
        <!-- when the main content is larger than main -->
        <div style="height: 1000px"></div>
      </div>
    </main>
    <footer>This is a footer</footer>
  </body>
</html>




Thanks for your reply. I tried this solution before, but when the main content is larger than main, the footer will be strange, which means it will behave like a fixed footer, but not a sticky footer.

Hi, code was updated for sticky footer.

This issue you are facing is because of how flexbox is handling the height of items. When you set height: 100% to the div#this_should_fill_main, it will try to take the 100 percent of its parent which is main. But issue starts here because main does not have a defined height because in a flex container, height of the child elements is defined by their content, except you say otherwise.
Another solution could be using properties of flexbox;

Add display: flex to main
You can also add flex-direction: column; to  your main if you want your content to displayed vertically.
Add flex-grow: 1 to div#this_should_fill_main so that it takes all available place of parent



main {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: flex; /* Add this to make main flex container */
  flex-direction: column; /* If you want your content to ve displayed vertically */
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
}

div#this_should_fill_main {
  flex-grow: 1; /* This is for div to grow all available space*/
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}



